# Scala + Spark - How to cast from 'scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef' to our custom object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

We are using `spark` along with `Scala` in our project.

We are using custom `encoders` to create `spark datasets`.

Our dataset schema is of type as below:

```
(String, util.ArrayList[MyObject])
```

When  we do df.printSchema, we get following:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- listOfMyObject: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: binary (containsNull = true)
```

MyObject is scala case class as below:

```
case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject2])
```

When we apply map function on this dataframe,

```
df.map((row) => {
val key  = row.get(0)
val values = row.get(1)
})
```

At runtime, row contains following schema:

```
StructField(key,StringType,true)
StructField(myObject,ArrayType(BinaryType,true),true)
```

We are able to retrieve the `String` value, but when trying to retrieve the `util.ArrayList[MyObject]`, we are getting `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef`.

We got this by using `ref.getClass` method.

Any pointers to solve this issue?

Thanks

Anuj

Comment: could you please provide more code?

Comment: added code for reference

Comment: please cast it like this `val values: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject] = row.get(1)` and let me know about the result

Comment: val values: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject] =
                row.getAs[java.util.ArrayList[MyObject]](1)
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 123 in stage 81.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 123.0 in stage 81.0 (TID 411, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: your data frame schema is different from `(String, util.ArrayList[MyObject])`. and this error says that compiler is not able to make a covariance between `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` and `java.util.ArrayList[MyObject]`. So please convert it to array of MyObjects 
 `row.get(1).toArray[MyObject]` and I hope it helps

Comment: we have;   val df = df with schema(string, myObject)

Comment: val dfGrouped =  df.groupBy(col("key"))

Comment: val finalDf =  dfGrouped.agg(collect_list("object") as "myObj")

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example. Is not clear what steps you followed and how you code looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Scala objects that spark can manage with the encoders, in your case you can change the `java.util.ArrayList` to a simple `List` of scala, and then if the order of the columns and the type is correct, transform your dataframe to a dataset of the type of your class only with this simple line:

```
case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: List[MyObject2])
val ds: Dataset[MyObject] = df.as[MyObject]
```

Keep in mind that if the schema you have an Array, yo can only transform it to List, no to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would change `java.util.ArrayList` by `scala.collection.immutable.List`

```scala
package playground

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
// import java.util.ArrayList

object Casting {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Casting")
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  case class MyObject2(fname: String, age: Int)

  // case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: ArrayList[MyObject2])
  case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: List[MyObject2])

  // val arrLst = new util.ArrayList[MyObject2]()
  // arrLst.add(MyObject2("Marie", 25))
  // arrLst.add(MyObject2("Peter", 27))

  val lst = List(MyObject2("Marie", 25),MyObject2("Peter", 27))

  // val data: Seq[MyObject] = Seq(MyObject("key",arrLst))
  val data: Seq[MyObject] = Seq(MyObject("key",lst))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import spark.implicits._

    try {
      val df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

      df.printSchema()
      df.map(row => {
        val key  = row.key
        val values = row.dataList
        (key, values)
      }).show(false)

      df.show()
    } finally {
      spark.stop()
      println("Spark Session has stopped.")
    }
  }
}
```

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- fname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: integer (nullable = false)

+-----+--------------------------+
|_1   |_2                        |
+-----+--------------------------+
|Lucia|[[Marie, 25], [Peter, 27]]|
+-----+--------------------------+
```

`ArrayList` it's not a member of `Scala collection`.
I would try to work with `Scala objects` that `Spark` can manage with its `encoders`.

Comment: I did;  val array = row.get(1).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[MyObject]].toArray   Getting following exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 123 in stage 81.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 123.0 in stage 81.0 (TID 411, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [B

Comment: instead of toArray, try toList. Why are you using ArrayList? is it mandatory to use it?

Comment: what else can i use instead of arraylist?

Comment: ArrayList it's not a member of Scala collection, you could try List for example. Have you tried val array = arr.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[MyObject]].toList.

Comment: yes.   val list = row.get(1).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[MyObj]].toList     then    last(0).getKey  --> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 123 in stage 81.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 123.0 in stage 81.0 (TID 411, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to com.MyObject

Comment: also list(0).isInstanceOf[MyObject]  returns false

Comment: I saw that is a List[MyObject2] not a List[MyObject] is that right

Comment: No, this is List[MyObject]. list(0) must return MyObject. MyObject then has MyObject2.  case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject2])

Comment: I don't see that, indeed in your post, your problem is with the util.ArrayList[MyObject] that belongs to case class MyObject(key: String, dataList: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject2]) and you are able to retrieve the String Key. Your DF is of Row[MyObject] that expanded to [String, WrappedArray] and you get String but not WrappedArray. First I think you have to change java.util.ArrayList by List or Array for example and then invoke asInstanceOf to cast WrappedArray to List or Array.

Comment: guess there is mis-communication. My Dataframe is of type (key: String, dataList: java.util.ArrayList[MyObject]). From here I and able to fetch 'key' which is of type String. But I am not able to fetch anything from MyObject. MyObject2 is inside MyObject.